# 13.04 Packages cannot be Authenticated

Tags: updates, ppa, authentication

I am unable to install updates because the following Packages cannot be authenticated:

```
libudev1 libxml2 libasound2 google-chrome-stable libgudev-1.0-0 libtiff5
  linux-image-3.8.0-19-generic libsystemd-daemon0 systemd-services
  nautilus-sendto-empathy gnome-control-center-signon libaccount-plugin-1.0-0
  mcp-account-manager-uoa account-plugin-yahoo account-plugin-salut
  account-plugin-jabber account-plugin-aim empathy empathy-common duplicity
  firefox-globalmenu firefox firefox-gnome-support firefox-locale-en
  flashplugin-installer gir1.2-gudev-1.0 linux-headers-3.8.0-19
  linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-19-generic
  linux-libc-dev python-libxml2 telepathy-idle thunderbird-globalmenu
  thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the follwing commands in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-key update
sudo apt-get update
```