# r-cran-matrix packages cannot be authenticated

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, update-manager

From command line, after entering `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  r-cran-matrix
Install these packages without verification [y/N]?
```

Alternatively, from Task Manager, I get

[image]

Many related solutions exist.  Trying [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/301525/115913) leads to

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://cran.rstudio.com precise/ Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253 KEYEXPIRED 1445181253
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
```

I seem to get an identical set of errors after working through the instructions in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10260634/2232265).

I also tried [this](https://serverfault.com/a/730464), which led to the following failures at the end of `apt-get update`:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two separate issues, and they are *not* related to each other, they're individually different issues.

The first is the `r-cran-matrix` issue, designated by the `E:...` line in your output.  The GPG key used for the signatures of that repository are no longer valid and expired.  You need to refer to the location of how you installed that repository to readd it and update the keys.

The second is you have two entries for Dropbox, denoted by the two `W:...` lines in the output.  Check all your `sources.list` file and your files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` for duplicate entries for Dropbox.  It looks like you have two entries that match based on that error.

Comment: I think I understood that there are two separate issues.  The mysterious thing was why the dropbox problem may have triggered the r-cran-matrix problem.  I've been a way from dropbox for a long time and regularly update my machine -- why would the dropbox lines have caused a problem now if not ever before?  Maybe there is no clean answer to this without digging more.  +1 for confirming my intuition.

Comment: @zkurtz Your reasoning was wrong and is wrong.  The Dropbox issue is separate.  Neither triggered each other.  Coincidence is to  blame with them showing up at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused because I have no idea how dropbox and cran would be connected, but I just did `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and removed both lines with `dropbox` in them and now `sudo apt-get update` works fine.  No worries about dropbox as I'm not using that anymore.

If anyone can post a relatively canonical answer, I'll be happy to give credit for that.

Comment: Firstly, post comments not answers.  Secondly, the errors aren't related, they're different.

Comment: I think on balance this probably *is* an answer. It was just a transitional issue with the package verification. Doing an `apt update` was the fix.